# About inctanceof in java

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

I would ask about.. do we use instanceof 
If there's  a class has an array of super class and the super class  has two sub-classes ..or more

For example: class team  has an array of person (aggregation relation)
And the class person is super 
The sub classes are   class player and  class couch )
Should I use increaseof in this method 
Void add_person( person p){

Comment: It is good to beside describing code example, showing it. For instance along of (or maybe even instead of) "class team has an array of person" you can include `class Team { Person[] array; ... }` to make your example clearer.

Comment: What would you want to do differently when adding a "player" person vs. a "couch" person? In other words, why would you need an instanceof decision? Most of the time, when you want to use instanceof, you better redesign your code (classes structure).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Team class is in the following form:

```
class Team{

Person[] personArr;

...
}
```

And your Player and Coach classes have the following relation with the Person class:

```
class Player extends Person{
...
}

class Coach extends Person{
...
}
```

and you have the following objects:

```
Coach tom = new Coach();
Player dick = new Player();
Person harry = new Player();

Team wolves = new Team ([tom, dick, harry]); //assume constructor
```

the following is the behavior of `instanceof`:

```
tom instanceof Coach //returns true
dick instanceof Player //returns true
tom instanceof Person //returns true
wolves instanceof Team //returns true
harry instanceof Person //returns true
harry instanceof Player //returns true
harry instanceof Coach //returns false
```